# jquery addClass to multiple links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, addclass

Is there any way I can addClass to multiple link? I have two different divs containing the same set of links; clicking upon a link should apply the same class to the "equivalent" link in the set of the other div.

```
<style>
.one{margin:70px 0}
.one a{ margin:10px; padding:5px 10px; background-color:green; text-decoration: none; color:white}
.selected{background-color: yellow;}
</style>
<div class="one">
<a href="#first">1</a><a href="#second">2</a><a href="#third">3</a>
</div>

<div class="two">
<a href="#first">1</a><a href="#second">2</a><a href="#third">3</a>
</div>
<script>
$("a.one").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass(".selected").filter(':first').click();
});
</script>
```

Comment: please can you explain bit more ? what you want the end result should be ?

Comment: i have 10 links inside first div and 10 inside second div. if i click first link from div one. class should applied to that link and same time class apply on second div first link. i hope question cleared.

Answer (score 0):

this code will helps you  ...

```
$("a").addClass(".selected");
```

Comment: but it will apply class to all the <a>?

Comment: have individual id for <a> tags and  using that id you can add a class for multiple tags .

Answer (score 0):

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/VA8uM/2/)

First you need to find the index of anchor .Then apply class in second div anchor based on that index.

```
$('.two').children('a').eq($('.one a').index(this)).addClass('selected');

 $('.one').children('a').eq($('.two a').index(this)).addClass('selected');
```

Comment: $(".one a").click(function(){
 $('.two').children('a').eq($('.one').index(this)).addClass('selected');
 $('.one').children('a').eq($('.two').index(this)).addClass('selected');
 });

Comment: applying color to second div 3rd link. its not applying to first or second links

Comment: @SalmanRazakMemon I created link see here http://jsfiddle.net/VA8uM/1/  But you need to remove class before apply

Comment: i gave link at top check this once

Comment: @Salman Razak Memon is it working for u.Let me know if you have any problem

Comment: it worked pretty well. Thanks bro
one more thing.

$(".one a").click(function(){
$(".two a").removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.two').children('a').eq($('.one a').index(this)).addClass('selected');
});

Comment: i've styled the second div links but it seems fixed with it. nothing is happening. Following is the style and script.
`code`.one{margin:70px 0}
.one a{ margin:10px; padding:5px 10px; background-color:green; color:white}
.two a{ margin:10px; padding:5px 10px; background-color:blue; color:white}
.selected{margin:10px; padding:5px 10px; background-color:yellow; text-decoration: none; color:black}
$(".one a").click(function(){
$(".two a").removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.two').children('a').eq($('.one a').index(this)).addClass('selected');
});

Comment: @Salman Razak Memon it is working fine see here i created another link http://jsfiddle.net/VA8uM/3/

Comment: @SalmanRazakMemon inthe second div links observe some "_" symbole is changing

Comment: .select got yellow background. its not applying on div.two links

Comment: @SalmanRazakMemon you need to remove blur colur applied first.Check it once by removing blue colour.Actually it is applying yellow colour

Comment: try to put styles for second links in a class and then try to apply that class

Answer (score 0):

I would try to introduce something in common with all the links that must change together. In this I introduced a class to identify them:

```
<style>
.one{margin:70px 0}
.one a{ margin:10px; padding:5px 10px; background-color:green; text-decoration: none; color:white}
.selected{background-color: yellow;}
</style>
<div class="one">
<a href="#first" class="1">1</a><a href="#second" class="2">2</a><a href="#third" class="3">3</a>
</div>

<div class="two">
<a href="#first" class="1">1</a><a href="#second" class="2">2</a><a href="#third" class="3">3</a>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.1").click(function() {
            $("a.1").addClass("selected");
            $("a:not(.1)").removeClass("selected");
        });
        $("a.2").click(function () {
            $("a.2").addClass("selected");
            $("a:not(.2)").removeClass("selected");
        });
       $("a.3").click(function () {
            $("a.3").addClass("selected");
            $("a:not(.3)").removeClass("selected");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Note: if the browser you are targetting does not support css3 you can't rely on :not selector and I should use some "old style" methods to remove the class.

Comment: i am using firefox ver 19.0.2

Comment: so you have support for :not selector :-) The problem could be with old browser; in that case you can write something like $("a.2, a.3").removeClass("selected"); to avoid the :not selector